# CSS layout issues only in IE7 positioning text over an image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, internet-explorer-7, center

So this layout is only causing problems in IE7. I'm trying to do a centered layout with 2 images around a video embed and have some text over one of the images. IE7 throws the text way over to the right. I'm not sure if IE7 is not handling the negative margin method for centering or some other issue.

I know it's not the overflow bug, because I took out the `overflow-x: hidden;` and got the same behavior. I'd be extremely grateful if anyone has any insight or solutions, thanks in advance!

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="hero">
    <img src="images/heroleft.jpg" alt="" />
    <p id="herotitle">WE ARE A VIDEO PRODUCTION<br />TEAM</p>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/22903076?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="622" height="350" frameBorder='0' border='0' style="border:0"></iframe>
    <img src="images/herofaderight.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff568;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

#hero{
    left: 50%;
    width: 1160px;
    margin-left: -580px;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
}

img,iframe{
    float: left;
}

p#herotitle{
    font-size: 36px;line-height: 38px;font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 36px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `left: 0` to `#herotitle` to make it work in IE7.

**See in IE7:** http://jsbin.com/avawo5

It's also worth pointing out that the way you're doing the entire page could be drastically simplified. If you'd like more details here, let me know.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. I would love some input, I'm very much a novice. The new site just went live btw, in case you were talking about the old one.